# Query Elasticsearch by id using the regex or wildcard filter

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I got a list of IDs:

```
bc2***********************13
b53***********************92
39f***********************bb
eb7***********************7a
80b***********************22
```

Each * is a unknown char and I need to find all IDs matching these patterns.

I tried the *regex* filter on field names like *id*, *_id* and *ID*, always with "bc2.*13" (or others) but always got no matches even for existing documents.

Comment: try non greedy match `bc2.*?13`

Comment: Can you post more details? Like the mapping of the index and the query you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `_id` field is not indexed : that's why you have no results.

Try setting `_id` field as `analyzed` in the mapping:

```
POST /test_id/
{
  "mappings":{
    "indexed":{
      "_id":{
        "index":"analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Adding some docs :

```
PUT /test_id/indexed/bc2***********************13
{
  "content":"test1"
}

PUT /test_id/indexed/b53***********************92
{
  "content":"test2"
}
```

I checked with one of your simple `regexp` query :

```
POST /test_id/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "_id": "bc2.*13"
    }
  }
}
```

Result :

```
"hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_id",
            "_type": "indexed",
            "_id": "bc2***********************13",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "content": "test1"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, that sounds reasonable.
I'll not try it in this case, because it's a quick on-time analysis on huge indices, indexing the _id isn't worth the resources just for this case.

Comment: Yes : I would advise not to do so as `_id` field won't be configurable anymore in ES v2.0 (see [this post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring)).

Answer (score 0):

If the `*`'s are of a known and constant length:

```
bc2.{23}13|b53.{23}92|39f.{23}bb|eb7.{23}7a|80b.{23}22
```

[DEMO](http://www.regexr.com/3balj)

Else:

```
bc2.*?13|b53.*?92|39f.*?bb|eb7.*?7a|80b.*?22
```

[DEMO2](http://www.regexr.com/3balm)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `_uid` field and the `wildcard` query:

```
GET yourIndex/yourType/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "_uid": "bc2***********************13"
    }
  }
}
```